# Cannot download tensorflow model of cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I was going to download [this](https://huggingface.co/cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M) model, and then I was going to save it later to be used with bert-serving. Since bert-serving only supports tensorflow model, I need to download the tensorflow one and not the PyTorch. The PyTorch model downloads just fine, but the I cannot download the tensorflow model. I used this code to download:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

model_name='cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M' 
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

Here's what I got when running the code on Ubuntu 16.04, python3.5, transformers==2.5.1,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 346, in from_pretrained
    assert os.path.isfile(resolved_archive_file), "Error retrieving file {}".format(resolved_archive_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
    st = os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: can't specify None for path argument
```

And here's what I got when running it on Windows 10, python 3.6.5, transformers 3.1.0:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_tf_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    579                 if resolved_archive_file is None:
--> 580                     raise EnvironmentError
    581             except EnvironmentError:

OSError:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c2f14f761f05> in <module>()
      3 model_name='cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M'
      4 tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
----> 5 model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_tf_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    585                     f"- or '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named one of {TF2_WEIGHTS_NAME}, {WEIGHTS_NAME}.\n\n"
    586                 )
--> 587                 raise EnvironmentError(msg)
    588             if resolved_archive_file == archive_file:
    589                 logger.info("loading weights file {}".format(archive_file))

OSError: Can't load weights for 'cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M'. Make sure that:

- 'cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or 'cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named one of tf_model.h5, pytorch_model.bin.
```

This also happens with other cahya/ models. [This page](https://huggingface.co/cahya/bert-base-indonesian-522M) says that you can use the tensorflow model. However, based on the error, it seems like the file does not exist over there?
I tried downloading other pretrained model like `bert-base-uncased` etc. and they download just fine. This issue only happens with cahya/ models.

Am I missing something? or should I report this issue to forum or the github issue?

Comment: Update: cahya has uploaded the model, so this is no longer relevant. https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/cannot-download-tensorflow-model-of-cahya-bert-base-indonesian-522m/1215/5

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be purely an issue of your environment.

Running the first code sample worked fine for me under Ubuntu 18.04 (I think using at least Ubuntu 16.04 should work as well, Windows 10 I cannot guarantee). I further use `transformers` 3.1.0, and `tensorflow` 2.3.0.

The first environment to me seems to be purely the fault of outdated versions for both Python (recommendation in general is at least 3.6+ currently, not even tied to `transformers` specifically), as well as the latest transformers release for full compatibility with models from the ModelHub.

For the second enviornment, I cannot full confirm this, but I supsect that it is due to path handling under Windows 10, as `transformers` needs to interpret paths as either an OS path, or ModelHub id.